# Nightwatch: Basic auth with access_key not working

Tags: selenium, testing, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

I created nightwatch.json file like below (with username and access_key properties):

```
"test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "http://localhost",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "cli_args": {
                "webdriver.firefox.profile": "testprofile"
            },
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": false,
                "path": "screenshots/"
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "firefox",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true
            },
            "username": "examplelogin",
            "access_key": "password"
        }
```

but basic auth don't work and I get login window to fill my password and login after running tests. I looked at packets in fiddler and no authorization header was present. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Nightwatch v0.9.6

Answer (score 2):

from: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nightwatchjs/n-B4HnnzYg8/rmaipXiTsuwJ

> Replying to my own post before - please don't confuse the username and
>   access_key vars as 'basic auth' ones. They are selenium based
>   authenticators which can optionally be used for authenticating against
>   cloud solutions. Best solution for basic auth is the good old URL way.
>   Try:  ``` browser.url('https://' + userName + ':' + password + '@' +
>   yourUrl)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `globals.js`. It will preserve credentials and skip basic auth prompt.

```
beforeEach: function (browser, cb) {
  if (browser.globals.basic_auth_url) {
    browser.url(browser.globals.basic_auth_url, cb);
  } else {
    cb();
  }
},
```

`basic_auth_url` - add full URL with credentials.

Do not add credentials to `launch_url`